# Jump out of for loop in kotlin

Tags: loops, for-loop, kotlin, break

I have this simple loop and condition, but you see below I can't jump out of loop :

```
rwloop@ for (z in rendered_words.size-1 downTo 0 )
                {
                    var css_=rendered_words[z].node.attr("class")
                    css_?.let {
                        if (css_=="classzero") {
                            break@rwloop
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But I receive this error in **break@rwloop** :

> break' or 'continue' jumps across a function or a
>   class boundary

Comment: You should be able to get rid of the `let`. The `==` expression would translate into `a?.equals(b) ?: (b === null)`

Comment: See also [Why can't use continue in let or run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62182565/why-cant-use-continue-in-let-or-run) for a workaround answer and a good forecast in [KT-1436](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1436).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns

It states that

> break and continue are not yet available in inlined lambdas, but we are planning to support them too.

So, you should

1. Wait until its support comes
2. Or use local return statement instead,

How?

The lambda is a function itself, so you can return from it, this (if it is the last thing in the for loop like your case) will make the same effect of continue

```
rwloop@ for(z in rendered_words.size-1 downTo 0 ) {
    var css_=rendered_words[z].node.attr("class")
    css_?.let {
        if (css_=="classzero") {
            return@let
        }
    }
}
```

Kotlin considers the lambda as a boundary (it is not an inner class because it is inlined), so you can't cross it by `break` nor `continue` till now.

Comment: Would that `return@let` really break out of the loop though? Wouldn't he need something like `run blabla@ { ... css?.let { ... return@blabla } }` ?  (or, since the `let` appears to be pointless in this code, he could just get rid of it and use `break` normally).

Answer (score 6):

Drop the let lambda since the @rwloop label is not visible inside it and use this:

```
        rwloop@ for (z in rendered_words.size-1 downTo 0 )
        {
            var css_=rendered_words[z].node.attr("class")
            if (css_ != null) {
                if (css_=="classzero") {
                    break@rwloop
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You don't need the label now. `break` automatically matches the innermost loop construct.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik True but the code already included the label so I did not change it. Plus I always use labels in Kotlin, just in case...